# How to enable floats in MNRAS LaTeX template?

Tags: floats

The MNRAS LaTeX guide for authors mentions the following:

> The LATEX float placement commands [htbp] are intentionally disabled. Layout of figures and tables will be adjusted by the publisher during the production process, so authors should not concern themselves with placement to avoid disappointment and wasted effort. Simply place the LATEX code close to where the figure or table is first mentioned in the text and leave exact placement to the publishers.

So \begin{figure}[H] has no effect.

But if I want to use [htbp] float commands, how do I re-enable them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you are submitting to their journal eabling floats will prevent submission, and if you are not, why use a journal class? the whole point of using publisher class files is to let the   publisher enforce their style and remove choice from the author.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand. Thank you. But if I want to use them with that format using MNRAS journal class, how can I go about it?